# Installing PySide without PIP

Tags: python, qt, pip, pyside

I'm trying to install PySide on my work computer. I got everything installed at home which was simple enough. However at work I'm stuck behind a firewall which I can't get around and therefore can't install PIP.

Is there a binary for PySide that I might be able to use or any other solution?

Thanks!

OS is Win 7 32-bit

Also I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: tried that https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows-7-or-graphical-install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it here (it is an executable):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyside

Enjoy! :)

Comment: Thanks that's got PySide installed for me.

Comment: That is not exe file Whl file how can i install?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the wheel distribution from PyPI [1] and install with PIP offline.

And you don't loose the benefits of installing packages via PIP.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#downloads

Here is direct link to package for your system and python version: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/P/PySide/PySide-1.2.2-cp34-none-win32.whl